# Optimization: minimize painting errors

Tags: math, optimization

You are given an m*n grid, where each cell is marked either "b" or "w". You are also given black and white paints. You are allowed to use k strokes, each of any color (black OR white), a stroke is defined as coloring of contiguous uncolored cells from the same row (which means a stroke can not go beyond the length of the row, also if you pick up your brush before the end of the row thats the end of that stroke). The aim is to minimize the number of errors, an error occurs if you paint a cell with wrong color OR a cell remains unpainted. What is the optimal strategy?

Comment: I doubt it. Homework wouldn't give something this "up in the air". Normally giving a problem in reference to a technique that is taught.

Comment: Not a complete answer so I'll just add it in a comment: since the rows are independent and the optimality/cost is known on each individual row, you can divide and conquer the problem of where to "spend" the k strokes. I'd start by looking at "branch and bound" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound

Comment: I'm guessing that "a stroke is defined as coloring of... cells from the same row" means the same row *or the same column*. That is, a stroke can be horizontal or vertical. Is that right?

Comment: @JimN no its not a homework problem.

Comment: @Beta: I have mentioned "from the same row" which means not columns, a stroke can only contain contiguous unpainted cells in a row.

Comment: what is the original source of the problem, is it online?

Comment: @ronalchn a really really tough onsite interview, I dont think this problem is NP but just want a confirmation from the community

Answer (score 0):

Knowing solution for one row problem (what is a minimal number of errors with k strokes on a given BW row) can be used to solve problem.

For each row make list of number of errors for given number strokes `k_i = [0, 1, ..., min k needed to cover i-th row]`. Now we have `n` lists (of different sizes). To find in which rows to use 'k' strokes, it is enough to iteratvely pop `k` elements from begining of list which stroke cover most cells.

So, main task is to solve one row problem, and I'm not sure how :-)

Let C be number of colour changes in a row. Than minimal number of strokes to cover row is a `ceil( (C+1)/2 )`. That can be done by alternate stroke colour with first stroke to cover whole row and next strokes between most distant change in a last stroke. First stroke has colour of one (or both) end(s).

I think , with similar approach it is possible to find number of errors when there isn't enough strokes to cover whole row. Some ranges of one colour have to be omitted. That is be done by:

- starting with colour that is not on a boundary (omitting first stroke),
- some strokes are not between most distant change in last stroke, but
  between closer changes.

I'm not sure, but it seems like it is enough to find few smallest same colour parts and that is what will stay as an error. Probably it is important how far these parts are from ends.

That is for now ...

Comment: "To find in which rows to use 'k' strokes, it is enough to iteratvely pop k elements from begining of list which stroke cover most cells." that is not the task. I think if you carefully read the problem statement again, you will realize the task is to spread k strokes over m rows in such a way that the error is minimized. I agree with your approach of assuming solution for a given row with 'x' strokes is available and using it for optimizing across rows, but I dont think the solution above is a solution to the problem statement at all..